# How to load file "synonyms.txt" present on remote server using solr?

Tags: solr

```
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Here file "synonyms.txt" is present in current directory . How to load this file if it's location is on remote server not on local machine ?

Answer (score 1):

**You can't load resource from remote. Instead you can http post request to put synonyms to your solr server with ManagedSynonymFilterFactory**

This featured introduced in Solr 4.8.0

How to Use :

First you have to declare your filter like below

```
<filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymFilterFactory" managed="english"/>
```

You can post Synonyms to solr with the below curl request :

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"mad":["angry","upset"]}' "http://solr_ip:8983/solr/collection_name/schema/analysis/synonyms/english"
```

Here change solr_ip and collection_name with yours. and i am putting word synonyms for mad is angry,upset

And you can check your synonyms by a get request.

```
http://solr_ip:8983/solr/collection_name/schema/analysis/synonyms/english
```

For more info : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Managed+Resources

Comment: I believe ManagedResources were introduced in the version of Solr after Solr 4. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreRafalovitch , Answer Edited :)

Comment: What about other filters, like DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilterFactory, which use a dictionary file but have no "managed" version? Isn't there a generic way of uploading such a file into the core configuration directory?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't just type in an URL because the `ResourceLoader` of the `SynonymFilterFactory` uses a `FilesystemResourceLoader`.

Thus said, you could still point Solr to anything that looks and behaves like a file, e.g. an NFS-mounted directory or even a locally synced Dropbox folder.